# Genus of $k(T)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a function field in one variable with total constant field $k$, let $X$ be the set of all places $F$, and let $S$ be a nonempty finite subset of $X$. Then the genus of $F$ is equal to the dimension over $k$ of the cokernel of $O_S \to \bigoplus_{v \in S} F_v/O_v$. My question is, what is the genus of $k(T)$?

Comment: Do you know all the places of $k(T)$?  If not, [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowskiF%28T%29.pdf) may be helpful.

Comment: If I understand well the genus does not depend on the choice of $S$. Is this true?